# Including a variant segment in product type template route in Commerce 2

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce2, products

Is it possible to use a wildcard when specifying the template path for a Commerce 2 product type?

I want to format my URLs as `/type/product/variant`
Where 'variant' could be a custom field applied to the product variant.

In the settings for my product type I've tried a few things, including setting the "Category URI Format" to variations of `/type/{slug}/{variant.customField}` all to no avail. The template isn't found as soon as I include that third segment to the URL.

I feel this should be possible to do with Routes but having much the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have figured out that instead of setting a template path in my product type I can leave that blank and use a custom route instead.

So in this case I set up a route for

`/type/*/*` -> `shop/variant`

It means I need to fetch the product entry manually in the template but that's no problem and it seems to be working.